# Taking user input while running while loop

Tags: c, stopwatch, fsm

So I am making stopwatch with c but I wanted to be able to take user input while the stopwatch is running.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "mylib/mylib.h"

void Delay(ms){
    clock_t timeDelay = ms + clock();
    while(timeDelay > clock());
}
void PrintData(int hour, int minute,  int second){
    printf(" %d:%d:%d \n", hour, minute, second);
    
    

    
}

void StopWatch(int hour, int minute, int second, int flag, int input){
    while(flag == 0){
        if (minute > 59){
            minute = 0;
            hour++;
        }
        if(second > 59 ){
            second = 0;
            minute++;
        }

        system("clear");
        PrintData(hour, minute, second);
        Delay(1000000);
        second++;

        
    }

    

}

int main(void){
    int s0 = 0, s1 = 0, S0 = 0, S1 = 0, b1 = 0, b2 = 0, O0 = 0, O1 = 0;
    int hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, flag = 0;
    int input;
    while(1){
        if ((S0 == 0 && S1 == 0)){
            if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 0){
                flag = 0;
                system("clear");
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 1;
                system("clear");
            }
            else if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 1;
                system("clear");
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 0){
                flag = 1;
                system("clear");
            }
            printf("Current state %d %d\n", S0, S1);
        }
        else if((S0 == 0 && S1 == 1)){
            if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 0){
                flag = 0;
                system("clear");
                PrintData(hour, minute, second);
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 1;
                system("clear");
                PrintData(hour, minute, second);

            }
            else if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 1;
                system("clear");
                PrintData(hour, minute, second);
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 0){
                system("clear");
                PrintData(hour, minute, second);
            }
            printf("Current state %d %d\n", S0, S1);
        }
        else if((S0 == 1 && S1 == 0)){
            if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 0){
                flag = 0;
                StopWatch(hour, minute, second, flag, input);
    
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 0;
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 0){
                PrintData(hour, minute, second);
            }
            printf("Current state %d %d\n", S0, S1);
        }
        else if((S0 == 1 && S1 == 1)){
            if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 0){
                flag = 0;
                system("clear");
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 0;
                system("clear");
            }
            else if(b1 == 1 && b2 == 1){
                flag = 0;
                system("clear");
                PrintData(hour, minute, second);
            }
            else if(b1 == 0 && b2 == 0){
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        b1 = 0;
        b2 = 0;
        printf("Insert input(1/2/3(both) \n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input == 1){
            b1 = 1;
            b2 = 0;
            
        }
        else if(input == 2){
            b1 = 0;
            b2 = 1;
        }
        else if(input == 3){
            b1 = 1;
            b2 = 1;
        }
        else if(input == 0){
            b1 = 0;
            b2 = 0;
        }
        else{
            input = 0;
        }
        



        states(s0, s1, b1, b2, &S0, &S1);
        s0 = S0;
        s1 = S1;









    }
    
  
    return 0;
    
}
```

`
I wanted to be able showing the current state and making an input while the stopwatch is running.
It should be showing the insert input and the current state while the stopwatch is counting.
I've tried to put the input on stopwatch function but it wouldn't work.
I've been tried many ways and comes up with nothing. I'm completely have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Where is `states()` defined?  Clearly state what your program is not doing that you want it to do.  Phrases like _"I've tried to put the input on stopwatch function but it wouldn't work."_ are not specific enough.  Also, provide only the code that is needed to illustrate and demonstrate the problem you need help with, in a [mcve]

Comment: Architecturally  getting user input while displaying elapsed time using console will be difficult.